# How to use sort() in combination with two filters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have two filters on an array and want to sort on alphabetic order. When i `log` the `const sortAlphabeticEnabled` it returns the names of the clients (from an i18n file) in alphabetic order. But it seems that is doesn't update the pårojects. Does anyone has an idea how to fix this? If you want i can upload the i18n file.

Answer (score 1):

Function passed to [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) accepts two parameters and has to return result of comparison of them (not just `true` or `false`). To compare string values you can use `.localeCompare()`.

Also you should do condition checking first in order to avoid extra operations:

```
const filteredCases = enabledCategoryFilter ? 
    allCases.filter(cases => cases.category.includes(enabledCategoryFilter)) : allCases;
filteredCases = awardFilterEnabled ?
    filteredCases.filter(cases => cases.awardWinning) : filteredCases;
filteredCases = sortAlphabeticEnabled  ? 
    filteredCases.sort((case1, case2) => case1.client.localeCompare(case2.client)) : filteredCases;
```

Otherwise JS enumerates array items regardless of whether you need filter it or not.

Answer (score 0):

`sort` takes two params (the two items compared right now) and returns 1, -1, 0 which are the result between these two items who suppose to be before.

It seems like you want to sort accord `item.client`, so something like this may do the trick (`(a.client > b.client)` is a bool going to evaluate as 1 or 0)

```
.sort((a, b) => sortAlphabeticEnabled ? (a.client>b.client)*2-1 : 0)
```

Comment: But is this sort in order which one is bigger than the other? Or is this order in alphabetic order? Because the default state of `sort()` is alphabetic. And that doesn't except two items compared to each other

Comment: yes, it is going to be order accords alphabetic order,  and you are right that `sort` by default it is alphabetic sorting, but at the moment you pass `cases` in, it not the array but just mapped item, and more than that for `sort` to not affect the array you should use `0` and not `true` as in `filter`

Comment: Be careful. This kind of comparison of strings may lead to unexpected results because they are encoded in utf-16